# Resultado de Busca com Angular em outra view

Tags: angularjs, algoritmo-de-busca

tenho um form de busca com 2 selects e 1 submit:

```html
<select ng-model="marca" ng-options="marca.nome_marca for marca in marcas" ng-change="changeMarca()">
<option value="">Selecione uma Marca</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="modelo" ng-options="modelo.nome_modelo for modelo in modelos|filter:{marca_id:marca.marca_id}" ng-change="changeModelo()">
<option value="">Selecione um Modelo</option>
</select>

<button ng-Click="???">BUSCAR</button>
```

Como posso fazer para exibir o resultado dessa busca em outra view, mais especificamente na rota que eu já tenho separado pra isso: `#/busca/:marca_id/:modelo_id`

Não sei se fui claro, eu já tenho as rotas todas, apenas preciso enviar isso para o controller de busca abaixo:

```js
angular.module("myApp").controller("buscaCtrl", function($scope, $http, $routeParams, estoqueAPI) {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.buscaMarca = $routeParams.marca_id;
    $scope.buscaModelo = $routeParams.modelo_id;

    var carregarEstoque = function () {
        estoqueAPI.getEstoque()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.carros = data;
        }).finally(function() { $scope.loading = false; })
    };

    carregarEstoque(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diante do trecho que você colocou na pergunta o único motivo para não estar funcionando como o esperado seria considerar os parâmetros ao fazer a requisição:

```js
angular.module("myApp").controller("buscaCtrl", function($scope, $http, $routeParams, estoqueAPI) {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.buscaMarca = $routeParams.marca_id;
    $scope.buscaModelo = $routeParams.modelo_id;

    var carregarEstoque = function () {
        estoqueAPI.getEstoque($scope.buscaMarca, $scope.buscaModelo)//<< considerar os parâmetros marca e modelo
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.carros = data;
        }).finally(function() { $scope.loading = false; })
    };

    carregarEstoque(); 
});
```

Agora... Se quer saber o que colocar no "ng-click" do botão "BUSCAR", então seria algo como:

```html
<button ng-Click="buscar()">BUSCAR</button>
```

E o controle:

```js
angular.module("myApp").controller("formCtrl", function($scope, $location) {
    
    $scope.buscar = function(){
        $location.path('/busca/' + $scope.marca.marca_id + '/' + $scope.modelo.modelo_id);
    };    
    
});
```

Comment: Afonso! Tudo fez muito sentido e realmente funcionou. A unica coisa que ainda não compreendi o porque, eu não estou recebendo o parametro $scope.marca e $scope.modelo no controller formCtrl. Alguma idéia de o porque disso? A pagina de resultado de busca esta tudo certo, fiz um teste manual com "#/busca/35/2736" e tudo certo, mas quando eu faço pelo formulario vem com valores: "#/busca/undefined/undefined".

Comment: Ops, estava inserindo no controller errado. Ajustei para o controller correto e esta funcionando tudo 100%. Muito obrigado Afonso!